# Is prefix needed for Struts2 namespace in forms and links?

Tags: java, struts2, namespaces

From the [Apache documentation](http://struts.apache.org/docs/namespace-configuration.html):

> While the prefix appears in the browser URI, the tags are "namespace
>   aware", so the namespace prefix does not need to be embedded in forms
>   and links.

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<package name="testpkg" namespace="/test" extends="struts-default">             
    <action name="doTest" class="otes.test.TestAction">
        <result>/success.jsp</result>
    </action>       
</package>
```

**`index.jsp`:** (`http://localhost:8080/nsdemo/`)

```
<h2>Using HTML tags:</h2>
<h3><a href="doTest">doTest without namespace</a></h3> <!-- 404 error -->
<h3><a href="test/doTest">doTest with namespace</a></h3> <!-- works -->

<h2>Using Struts2 tags:</h2>
<h3><s:a href="doTest">doTest without namespace (s:a href)</s:a></h3> <!-- 404 error -->
<h3><s:a href="test/doTest">doTest with namespace (s:a href)</s:a></h3> <!-- works -->

<!-- 404 error -->
<s:url action="doTest" var="myAction" />
<h3><s:a href="%{myAction}">doTest without namespace (s:url action)</s:a></h3>

<!-- works -->
<s:url action="test/doTest" var="myAction" />
<h3><s:a href="%{myAction}">doTest with namespace (s:url action)</s:a></h3>
```

Does this mean I really have to specify the namespace in my forms and links?

(I am using Struts 2.3.20 if that matters.)

Comment: *the tags* refers to S2 tags.

Comment: You mean tags like `<s:form>`?

Comment: Yes, and `<s:url>` and `<s:a>`.

Comment: `<s:a href="doTest">Do Test</s:a>` returns 404 too.

Comment: `href` isn't evaluated, use `action` or construct url-s using `<s:url>`.

Comment: I edited my post to include the struts2 tags in the test. `<s:url action>` also returned 404 when there was no namespace prefix.

Comment: In which namespace was your page where do you test those links? If it not the `/test` how do S2 should guess to which action in which namespace you referring? Imagine you have another package with different namespace with `doTest` action.

Comment: There is `namespace` attribute for namespaces. And don't put extension in `action` attribute -> `<s:url action="doTest">`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to put an answer? I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: the tags referred in the docs are Struts2 tags (e.g. `<s:url>`, `<s:a>`).

And *namespace aware* means that if you already executed some action in particular namespace then in the JSP you don't need to prefix S2 links and forms with the **current** namespace.

E.g. if you have this package configuration:

```xml
<package name="testpkg" namespace="/test" extends="struts-default">             
    <action name="index">/index.jsp</action>
    <action name="doTest" class="otes.test.TestAction">
        <result>/success.jsp</result>
    </action>       
</package>
```

and executed the `index` action (http://localhost/app/test/index.action). Then in index.jsp you can write

```xml
<s:a action="doTest">test</s:a>
```

and that url will take you to the same namespace.

If you want to change namespace there is `namespace` attribute in some tags that you can use.

E.g. you are in some page (http://localhost/app/index.action) - note no namespace in url, then following link will execute `doTest` in `/test` namespace.

```xml
<s:a action="doTest" namespace="/test">test</s:a>
```

BTW don't add action extension to actions in S2 tags.

This is **wrong**:

```xml
<s:form action="doTest.action">
```

This is **correct**:

```xml
<s:form action="doTest">
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Might there be a typo in the `<s:form action action>`? (There are 2 `action` attributes.)

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple: if you defined a package with the namespace attribute then its actions belong to this namespace. And when you use `url` or `a`, or `form` tags you should specify a namespace attribute along with action name which is in action attribute. If you specify both parameters Struts can easy map your URL to the action from the package with namespace. Don't use action extension in these attributes. Struts is using `UrlHelper` class to build the url and if it can't find the action mapping it will return the string as is. Also if you are using href attribute then Url helper is not involved, so the string remains as is.

This code should work:

```
<s:url namespace="/test" action="doTest" var="myAction" />
<h2><s:a href="%{#myAction}">doTest with href (s:url action)</s:a></h2>
<h2><s:a namespace="/test" action="doTest">doTest with namespace and action (s:url action)</s:a></h2>
```

Comment: "when you use `url` or `a`, or `form` tags you should specify a namespace attribute along with action name" - Thank you for making this clear to me. :)