# Attribute namespace in the Struts2 form tag not working

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I'm currently using Struts2 (2.3.7) and i'm facing with the following issue.
When i specify a namespace `/x` in the form tag on my jsp:

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:form namespace="/x">
    <s:submit action="z" />
</s:form>
```

the html form tag that is generated contains `y` that is different from declared `x`:

```jsp
<form action="/contextRoot/y/z.action" method="post">
```

where `y` is the namespace of the previous request, so it seems that attribute namespace has no effect. I know that tags are "namespace aware" [Is prefix needed for Struts2 namespace in forms and links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052686/is-prefix-needed-for-struts2-namespace-in-forms-and-links) but i want to specify a different one.

Comment: Put some `action` to your form as well.

Comment: @AleksandrM Ok, now it works. So namespace attribute doesn't work as i excpected. It is used for something else ?

Comment: Does `z.action` have the same name on both the namespaces ?

Comment: Well guess I should explain that.

Comment: @Andrea No, z.action is defined only on x namespace. The solution suggested by AleksandrM works perfectly. I guess attribute namespace on struts2 form tag make sense only when the action attribute is defined in the same tag.

Comment: I know, Namespace is simply ignored, and the action in the form is the same that dispatched the JSP. I was waiting your feedback before answering the question because it's not clear to me why it should put the s:submit action in the s:form action, unless they are the same. You've probably posted the content of the s:submit action, not the s:form one, do you ? BTW it's better @AleksandrM answered since his comment was the answer itself, and just needed to be expanded.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Which reminds me that I forgot to answer question in the answer. :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: The code is clear. I usually put submit tags inside form tags especially when i need more than one submit. Anyway we can considering closed the issue!

Comment: So you came from `old_Namespace/old_Action.action`, use `<s:form namespace="/new_Namespace">
    <s:submit action="new_Action" />
</s:form>` and in the HTML you get `<form action="/contextRoot/old_Namespace/new_Action.action" method="post">` ? I'd expect `<form action="/contextRoot/old_Namespace/old_Action.action" method="post">`

Comment: @AndreaLigios Sorry, i didn't understand your question. The html content was referred to s:submit. Thank you for noticing me the mistake. According to that I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr

Put some `action` attribute to your `<s:form>` tag as well.

Explanation:

If there is no `action` attribute in the `<s:form>` tag then the form action url defaults to current request url. i.e. Action and namespace come from current request. Side effect of this is that `namespace` attribute on `<s:form>` tag is simply ignored.

Example:

Current request: `app/some_namespace/some_action`

And the form:

```
<s:form namespace="/x">
    <s:submit action="z" />
</s:form>
```

Will produce something like that for the form url:

```
app/some_namespace/some_action
```

and for the submit button:

```
app/some_namespace/z
```